# Display dynamically nested data

Tags: angular

What would be the best way to display some **dynamically nested data** like this?

```
const data = [
  { name: 'Paul', children: [
    { name: 'John'},
    { name: 'Rachel', children: [
      { name: 'Abraham' }, 
      { name: 'Diana' }, 
      { name: 'Sara', children: [
        { name: 'Johan' }
      ]}
    ]},
    { name: 'George', children: [
      { name: 'Stewart' }
    ]},
    { name: 'Andrew' }
  ]},
  { name: 'Richard' }
];
```

Result should be:

- Paul

  - John
  - Rachel

    - Abraham
    - Diana
    - Sara

      - Johan
  - George

    - Stewart
  - Andrew
- Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwodqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist.component.ts)

You can create a component as follows

What this component does is to take an array and display it within `li` and call itself again with `children`

`list.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: `
    <ul *ngIf="data">
      <li *ngFor="let row of data">
        {{row.name}}
        <list [data]="row.children"></list>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class ListComponent  {
  @Input() data: any[];
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<list [data]="data"></list>',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [
    { name: 'Paul', children: [
      { name: 'John'},
      { name: 'Rachel', children: [
        { name: 'Abraham' }, 
        { name: 'Diana' }, 
        { name: 'Sara', children: [
          { name: 'Johan' }
        ]}
      ]},
      { name: 'George', children: [
        { name: 'Stewart' }
      ]},
      { name: 'Andrew' }
    ]},
    { name: 'Richard' }
  ];
}
```

Comment: The perfect one!

Comment: Awesome solution